# Why does my touchpad driver randomly becomes unresponsive?

Tags: drivers, touchpad

I am using a Toshiba S855-S5378 running windows 8 with Synaptics touchpad driver. When this happens, the touchpad driver did not start up when it's supposed to. I also can't open the mouse settings in control panel. The startup entry of the touchpad driver is still there. The only thing I can do right now is to uninstall the touchpad driver, remove all it's files, and reinstall it again. Then it works as normal until it goes unresponsive again next time. There are no warnings or whatnot.

This seems to happen randomly. Sometimes I have a week before the problem came back. Sometimes I can go for a couple of months with no problems, only to have it haunt me again.

I tried several tests and I can't seem to find the problem. These are not the cause of the problem: Windows update, Slimdrivers updates, Filehippo updater, CCleaner Scan, Virus Scan, Glary Utilities Scan, Installing/uninstalling programs from add/remove programs.

Comment: It goes Absent Without Leave? :)  Are you using the [latest Synaptics driver](http://www.synaptics.com/resources/drivers)?

Comment: No, this driver won't work. I have to install the drive from my manufacturer website. 

http://www.csd.toshiba.com/cgi-bin/tais/support/jsp/modelContent.jsp?ct=DL&os=&category=&moid=3478693&rpn=PSKFUU&modelFilter=S855-S5378&selCategory=2756709&selFamily=1073768663

Comment: Ok, are you using the latest one offered by Toshiba? Are you sure you're not accidentally hitting the Touchpad enable/disable toggle key? I think it's F9 on that device, maybe F5, check your manual to be sure. :)

Comment: Yes I'm using the latest version.

No. When this problem happens, it's not that the touchpad is not on. It's that my custom touchpad settings is all reset to default and I can't access to the settings.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience when using toshiba laptops the is a weird little feature when using the touchpad. in the top right hand corner of the touch pad is a area that is double tapped will disable the the touchpad I have had many a user complain about the driver dying or something similar.

Try tapping the portion of the touchpade there is usually a icon or a emblem that signifies that it will disable the touch it's usually really small so most don't notice it.